# Firebase invalid credentials on Android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

That's my concern, currently I'm developing an application that uses Firebase. Recently my identifiers for Android no longer work, the error tells me that the App ID does not match, however I am using google-services.json provides from my firebase console after adding my android application with its SHA key- 1.

My file is inside android/app folder like Firebase want it.

I have no problem with my iOS application, everything works fine.

Do you think I should try to delete Android ***ID clients OAuth 2.0*** from google cloud platform and try to recreate it ?

Answer (score 0):

it works, delete and recreate everything works, because Firebase works independently : if you delete an app inside your firebase console, it doesn't delete it inside google cloud platform.